# Получение полного исходного кода сайта C# (Аналог Ctrl+Shift+I в Google Chrome)

Tags: php, c#, html, парсер

Добрый день. Решая задачу связанную с парсингом сайта наткнулся на проблему.
Есть страница сайта суда, где ежедневно публикуются объявления о банкротстве (http://vgsu.arbitr.gov.ua/pages/157) . Как можно видеть из исходного сама форма поиска и таблица с объявлениями спрятана в php документе. Если попытаться получить исходный код сайта с помощью Google Chrome (нажать "Посмотреть код")  то можно получить полнейший текст сайта, откуда можно спарсить необходимую информацию. 
При получении же исходного кода через С# (HttpRequest или получение кода с элемента WebBrowser.DocumentText) дает сжатую версию кода.
Как можно в C# получить полнейший код сайта как в Google Chrome?

Заранее благодарю!

Наглядно:
в C# я получаю

```
 <TD><iframe name="forma" src="http://ovsb.ics.gov.ua/view/vgsu/bankrut.php" width="100%" height="2200px" align="left" frameborder="no" scrolling="" >No Frame Support!</iframe>
```

а через Google Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I (Где уже есть конкретная информация о количестве записей. Выделил красным)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под сжатой ? То, что вместо кода скрипта Вы видите его подключение ?
`<script src="..."></script>`

Comment: И еще вопрос: `Ctrl-Shift-U` или же `Ctrl-U`. Несущественно, конечно. Однако `Ctrl-U` работает, а второй вариант - нет.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос с подробностями. Ctrl+SHIFT+I, поправил

Comment: Делал подобное. С сервисом мониторинга аккций. Есть скрипт. Есть csv-файл. Скрипт тянет csv, парсит его, и то, что Вы видите у себя на экране - это его содержимое. Подебажьте, так ли это в Вшем случае.Если не получится, могу я попробовать.

Comment: можно поподробнее о данном способе?

Comment: Могу предположить, что Вы подумали, будто сервис "прячет" часть кода ) Вы надеялись увидеть какой-то "код" внутри div'а, отмеченного на картинке. На самом деле, есть скрипт, который который подгружает CSV-файл с данными, парсит его, а затем уже это все "отрисовывается" этим же скриптом, или php, не знаю. Вы понимаете разницу между страницей статической и динамической ?)

Comment: да, понимаю. то есть грубо говоря если вся информация хранится на сервере в csv то без доступа к нему я никак не смогу спарсить данные?

Comment: Думаю, сможете ))) Тут есть фильтрация - раз есть фильтры, то CSV формируется где-то на сервере, а скрипт его подгружает, зная его URL-адрес. Посмотрите, как формируется запрос при использование фильтров, формируйте аналогичный у себя и будет все хорошо.

Comment: Пример: скрипт тянет CSV по url: `http://service.com/storage` - в этом случае загрузится CSV со всеми записями. Допустим, st означает стартовую дату, et - конечную, тогда `http://service.com/storage?st=12.02.2012&et=12.02.2013` уже вернет вам csv с записями за один год ))

Comment: нужно искать это в исходниках всех js скриптов?

Comment: Просто сделать запрос адреса `https://ovsb.ics.gov.ua/view/vgsu/bankrut.php` нельзя?

Comment: @Monk пробовал, но все равно выдается код php страницы со скриптами без конкретной информации

Comment: И не получится.HttpRequest вернет Вам именно тот код, что Вы видите на скриншоте, он просто "не дождется" того момента, когда отработает скрипт. Говорят, есть хитрые способы, отправить запрос, ожидать некоторое время, и лишь потом возвращать результат, но я не знаю, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не загаживать комментарии, оформлю в отдельный ответ. В Вашем случае поиск нужных записей осуществляется при нажатии клавии "Пошукать" )) У кнопки есть идентификатор `#search`. Ищете в коде этот идентификатор (в скриптах). В Вашем случае - это самый первы подключенный скрипт. Далее, дебажите, или просто разбираете js-код. Когда разберетесь, будете знать, как формируется url для загрузки CSV. Все.

По поводу веб-клиента. Вот вы открываете в браузере эту страницу - все видите, пробуете сделать это в C# через веб-клиент - никак. А почему ? А потому что браузер у Вас подгрзуит скрипты, и они отработают. Веб-клиент никаких скриптов не подгружает и не должен этого делать.

Comment: Собственно вот до чего я дошел. POST запрос передается на страницу https://ovsb.ics.gov.ua/view/vgsu/bank_content.php с параметрами в "sEcho=4&iColumns=9&sColumns=&iDisplayStart......."   но когда я просто пытаюсь вставить это в строку браузера у меня вылетает 403 Forbidden :c

Comment: Вот Вам [curl запрос](https://jpst.it/MAzU), надеюсь, теперь сможете разобраться до конца.